# Maintaining RTF formatting from clipboard using HTML tags

Tags: sublimetext2

My question is as follows: In SublimeText2 (or 3), how can I take RTF formatted text in the clipboard and buffer them with HTML tags so when I paste in Sublime Text I get the following:

Text to be copied from word/rtf: Here are *some* **words**

Once pasted into Sublime Text: `Here are <i>some</i> <b>words</b>.`

How would I go about this?

Comment: It sounds like you need an RTF2HTML converter.  Search for one and see if they work for you.  That, or try pasting RTF into a web page tool -- or try saving as HTML from a word processor -- but you will probably find limited success here (Deamweaver does not recognize RTF and Word adds lots of other markup).  It is hard to imagine a need for such a package in Sublime.

Answer (score 0):

use [Sublime Highlight](https://github.com/n1k0/SublimeHighlight) it has lots of conversions for formatted code